# The program crashes after executing while loop

Tags: c++, while-loop

The code shuts down after executing the while loop and does not execute the last 2 printf statements. I don't know whats wrong.. after the loop goes around for the chosen times the program just closes.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main()
{
    int numberofq;
    int questionansc;
    int questionansic;
    int counter;
    int answer;

    numberofq = 0;
    questionansc = 0;
    questionansic = 0;
    counter = 0;
    answer = 0;

    while(numberofq <1 || numberofq >5)
    {
    printf("Hello enter the amount of questions you want between 1 and 5 \n");
    scanf("%d", &numberofq);
    } // End While

    //Program runs until the counter is less than users wanted question number.
    while (counter < numberofq)
    {
        //Question 1
        printf("Question 1. what is 2+2? \n");
        scanf("%d" , &answer);

        //if users answer is equal to 4.
        if (answer == 4)
        {
        printf("You entered %d, you are correct\n", answer);
        questionansc = questionansc +1;
        } //End If

        //If the answer is not equal to 4.
        else 
        {
        printf("You entered %d, you are wrong correct answer is 4 \n", answer);
        questionansic = questionansic +1;
        } // End Else

        counter = counter +1;
        //End Question 1.

    } //End While

        printf("You got %d questions correct \n" , questionansc);
        printf("You got %d questions wrong" , questionansic);
        flushall();

        return 0;
} // End Main`
```

Comment: Add the language you're using to the tags.

Comment: Tip - you can initialize (set to 0, in your case) variables in the same line you declare them.

Answer (score 1):

It actually prints them and **then** exits, but it exits so quickly you don't have a chance to see this.
You can pause execution using `system("pause")` on Windows, but that's considered bad practice. You could use `getch()` or something, but you could also simply invoke the program from an existing CMD/Terminal and in this way the output will stay there after the program is done.